# how to take the second part of the message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a command like:

```
+channel [name] [category]
```

My code is all working, but I'm not sure how to take the [name] and the [category] as different variables- I used

```
args.join(" ")
```

So my bot takes everything I say after the prefix and command as the channel name. Thanks in advance and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly so you have a string as a `command`
for example

```
+channel [name] [category]
```

so what you need is to parse it and get each part in a variable,

you could do something like this using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let command = '+channel test cat_test'
const [channel, name, category] = command.split(' ');

console.log(channel) // +channel
console.log(name) // test
console.log(category) // cat_test
```